# In Salesforce CRM Analytics: I would like to generate a reference date. There seems to be no dateOffset/ dateAdd function

Tags: salesforce, analytics

In Salesforce CRM Analytics, I have a pretty simple query:
Look at this month, last month, 2 months ago, etc.
Show currentMonthlyRecurringRevenue.
All the filters, groupings, sums are all easy.
I manually named each column something like "last month", "2 months ago", etc.
However, I would like to show a real date like "July 2023" or even "1 July 2023" in the column header.
I cannot find a way to do this.
There is nothing like:  dateOffset(now(), -1, 'MONTH') as 'Reference Date'
Any ideas?

---

```
q_A = filter q by date('currentCLIStartDate_Year', 'currentCLIStartDate_Month', 'currentCLIStartDate_Day') in [.."2 months ahead"] && date('currentCLIEndDate_Year', 'currentCLIEndDate_Month', 'currentCLIEndDate_Day') in ["2 months ahead"..];

q_A = group q_A by rollup('Product2.Name');
q_A = foreach q_A generate q.'Product2.Name' as 'Product2.Name', sum(q_A.'currentMonthlyRecurringRevenue') as **'A'**, grouping(q_A.'Product2.Name') as 'grouping_Product2.Name';
```

Thanks so much!

I have tried things like dateOffset() DateAdd().  None of those seem to be valid functions in the foreach section.